# What happen exactly after merge two accounts of one stackexchange site?

Tags: support, merge-accounts

What happen with the old account? It disappear? All the activity of the old account will appear as if were made by the new account at first instance or in some way is marked the old account activity in the new account?

Comment: Yes there is a merging in accounts so based on whatever is appropriate, the reputation and the user activities are merged. I don't think it is about the old or new account. But if it is merged due to suspicious activity then the account which is more suspicious is removed and activity is merged with other account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All account activity is merged into the first account, at which point, reputation and certain badges (like Pundit) are recalculated. No distinction is made between the two accounts, because they're the same person.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what of the two username prevails?

Comment: Whichever account you completed the merger while logged into keeps your username.

Comment: How long will it usually take for this merging to occur after the confirmation links have been clicked?